# How to fetch username from other table user_id store in other table

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table "articles" in this table a column name "user_id", I have another table "users" where store username, profile_pic etc... I want to fetch username on home page where I already fetched articles title.

**Article Model**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Article extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

**View Page(Home Page)**

```
{{$article->user_id}}
```

Here I want to Display username

**User Model**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to Article class:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Then you can access related user data with `$article->user->name`